Precision Full-Wave Rectifier doesnt work properly
I’m having some frustration with this circuit (Precision Full-Wave Rectifier) as shown in TI Precision Designs:, although I’m using an LM358N, the document references the OPA2211. I simulated the circuit in LTSpice with the LM358N and everything seems fine, but the problem arises when I move to hardware, where I don’t get any significant results. I’m sharing the breadboard assembly prints and the wiring diagram; am I making an obvious mistake here? By the way, I’m using a DSO153 to generate my input signal and analyze my output. Can anyone help me? Sorry for Image spam!
LTspice Simulation:

BreadBoard schematic:

Hardware circuit:

Input:

Output:

positive supply rail:


Your diagram has an error -- the position of the lowest 1K resistor is off by one. However, this error is not repeated on the actual breadboard in the photograph.

Is your negative rail on the bottom connected? All I see in it is the 56Ω resistor, but we can't see the whole board. Is it connected at the other end and if so are the rails continuous (some boards break them in the middle)? Can you give us a pic that shows the whole board?

Hi, yes, It was connected to the other side of the breadboard, and even if I remove the 56-ohm resistor, apparently nothing changes!

@bananas867 The 50Ω resistor in the original circuit is for impedance matching with the signal generator, and will only attenuate the input (depending on your signal generator output settings). It won't alter the the behaviour of the circuit otherwise.

I don't see any wiring errors, so I am suspicious of the power supplies. I would like to see an oscillogram of the positive supply rail.

@SimonFitch The positive supply rail appears to be in good condition to me! [Edited by a moderator to remove obsolete information.]

@bananas867 Well, then, I suppose you'll have to do what everybody else here would do. Check all connections for continuity with your multimeter. Test the op-amps, perhaps cascade two voltage followers (each loaded with 1k to ground) to see if they follow. That kind of thing. 9 times out of 10 it's a wiring error. There's nothing here, be it the op-amps or the frequencies that would cause oscillation, so I have to guess wiring error, or some breadboard problem. Unless you are using stupidly long wires anywhere, in huge loops. That might cause some wiggles.

I don't know what's wrong. I tested everything—the IC is fine, the wires are okay as well. I even tried a differents capacitors, and with 10nF for example, I get a clean output, but it's not rectifying. I'm just getting the same input wave on my output.

If you run the same simulation with a faster opamp, the OP227, the simulation shows everything going haywire - very unstable. I don't know if this points to a marginal circuit design or is a complete red herring.

I'm suspecting it might be due to my cheap function generator. I just realized how much DC offset it has when generating a sine wave, for example, when I generate sine 2Vpp, it generate 1V DC offset, and that could be causing this discrepancy, I need to test it with a real function generator.

If DC offset from your generator is a concern, just AC-couple it to your circuit: put a 0.1uF or 0.47uF in series from your generator to the opamp input, and increase the pulldown resistor to 100K (there's no reason to have such a stiff low impedance there, and a 100K with 0.1uF forms a high pass filter at 16Hz, enough to pass your signal easily).
